# How to fix "Can't locate Archive/Tar.pm"

Tags: perl

I'm trying update a software and when I running for make update I've a issue:

```
Can't locate Archive/Tar.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ...)
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: I've look into version you're right. I'm running 5.16 and have this problem. It's a major problem

Comment: @LuanBarbosa which system? redhat or centos maybe? you have to install the `perl-core` package, as the perl package itself doesn't include all perl core modules.

Comment: I'm using RedHat 7. Thank you very much. I've installed the core package and works now. The problem  was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Archive::Tar has been bundled with Perl since Perl 5.10, so unless you are using an ancient version of Perl, you have a partial or corrupted install of Perl.

Some Linux distributions (e.g. Redhat) gut out lesser-used parts of Perl and provide them in an package (e.g. `perl-core`) that can be installed using the OS distribution's package manager.

Alternatively, Archive::Tar is available for install separately from Perl —it is ["dual-lived"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009476/what-is-a-dual-life-module)— so you can [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module) it from CPAN.